# API de Pagamento com suporte a cobrança automatica variável

Tags: web-service, api, pagamento-online

Existe alguma API de Pagamento com suporte a assinatura com valor variável. Ou melhor, esquema pós pago.

Se o usuário gastou X, paga Y. Se não gastou nada, não paga nada. Se gastou 5X paga 5Y.

Já uso o **pagseguro** para operações pré paga, mas na [documentação](http://download.uol.com.br/pagseguro/docs/pagseguro-assinatura-automatica.pdf) dele a descrição de assinatura, o valor é fixo.

Comment: Como você calcula quanto o usuário gastou? É só mandar o valor para a API.

Comment: @KaduAmaral, fazer isso com a API padrão, eu teria que fazer uma compra a cada uso. É impraticável!

Comment: O custo é baseado no uso do serviço sob demanda. Imagine se fosse o Netflix, seria baseado no numero de filmes que o usuário assistiu. Ou em outro serviço de streaming, baseado no numero de horas que o usuário usou. Estou falando de uma autorização para cobrança automática. Quem sabe com suporte a custo máximo por mês.

Comment: Entendi, você pode entrar em contato diretamente com o [pagseguro](https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/atendimento/contato_comercial.jhtml), para ver se eles atendem sua necessidade.

Comment: Na verdade o pagseguro já suporta o que você quer: http://download.uol.com.br/pagseguro/docs/pagseguro-assinatura-manual.pdf.